# Camel to SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, apache-camel, activemq-classic

HighLevel: I need data from ActiveMQ to feed into Salesforce. Data will be XML format.

I have an ActiveMQ queueing system with Apache Camel on top. What I would like to do is have Camel push messages to Salesforce. I'm wondering what I will need in between Camel and Salesforce to accomplish this. Anyone have experience with this or know ANYTHING about it?

Answer (score 1):

start with the [camel-salesforce](http://camel.apache.org/salesforce.html) component...

if doesn't meet your needs, follow up with a question about the specific features/functionality that you are looking for